# Relationship between differential and derivative for non-linear functions

Tags: calculus

Let us assume that we have a function:
$$
y=f\left(x\right)
$$
If $f\left(x\right)$ is linear and equal to $ax$, then we obtain:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=a
$$
where $a$ is the linear coefficient. However, in this case, if we
take the differential of $y,$ we get
$$
dy=a\times dx
$$
which is re-written as:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=a
$$
In this case, we can think of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a ratio of the
change in $y$ to the change in $x.$ However, I have read elsewhere
that $\frac{d}{dx}$ is best thought of as an operator that operates
on $y$. Is the distinction in a non-linear setting? In other words,
assume we have:
$$
y=f\left(x\right)
$$
where $f(x)$ is non-linear. The differential of $y$ gives:
$$
dy=f'\left(x\right)dx
$$
Can the derivative be derived in this setting equivalently?